# Design a rank one matrix $\boldsymbol{C} = \boldsymbol{a} \boldsymbol{b}^T$ to make there exists no same value in the matrix $\boldsymbol{C}$.

Tags: matrices

I wanto to design a rank one matrix $\boldsymbol{C} = \boldsymbol{a} \boldsymbol{b}^T \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$. The matrix $C$ should not have same values, the vector $ \boldsymbol{a} $and $\boldsymbol{b} $ are supposed to satisfy $ \| \boldsymbol{a} \|_2 \leq 1$ and $  \| \boldsymbol{b} \|_2 \leq 1$. In my question, $m ,n $ are supposed to be large enough, which means $\min {m,n} \geq 256$.

In fact, when $m,n$ are small, I can carefully choose values to statisfy these constraints. However, is there any law to design a huge matrix like that? Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: The question is that you want the $C_{i,j}$s to be all different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your values simple fractions, then you can take advantage of some elementary number theory. For example, $2^a3^b=2^c3^d$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$. Can you see how to use that fact?

*Edit*: Okay, here's my full answer:

$$\pmatrix{\frac12\\\frac14\\\frac18\\\vdots\\\frac{1}{2^m}}\pmatrix{\frac13&\frac19&\frac{1}{27}&\cdots&\frac{1}{3^n}}=
\pmatrix{
\frac16&\frac{1}{18}&\frac{1}{54}&\cdots&\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^n}
\\
\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{108}&\cdots&\frac{1}{4\cdot 3^n}
\\
\frac{1}{24}&\frac{1}{72}&\frac{1}{216}&\cdots&\frac{1}{8\cdot 3^n}
\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots
\\
\frac{1}{2^m\cdot3}&\frac{1}{2^m\cdot9}&\frac{1}{2^m\cdot27}&\cdots&\frac{1}{2^m\cdot 3^n}
}$$

Comment: Thanks! But why $2^a 3^b = 2^c 3^d$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$. I check the figure of this function, it shows that for $c \neq a$ and $d\neq b$, it can have same values.

Comment: @KrisProkins (I'm assuming that $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are all integers)